# Calculate Integral Using Fourier Series?

Tags: fourier-series

I got this integral that I have been asked to calculate:
$\int_{0}^{2\pi} |3+4e^{10ix}+5e^{100ix}|^{2}dx$

I tried using Parseval's identity and tried to convert it to Fourier series.
I think there is an easy way to solve it that I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier way: just multiply the integrand out.

$$\begin{align}|3+4e^{10ix}+5e^{100ix}|^{2} &= (3+4e^{10ix}+5e^{100ix})(3+4e^{-10ix}+5e^{-100ix})\\ &= 9 + 16 + 25 +  \text{cosine terms} \end{align}$$

The integral over the cosine terms is zero (why?)  Therefore, your answer is $50 \cdot 2 \pi = 100 \pi$.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{inx}dx = [-{ie^{inx}\over n}]_{0}^{2\pi} = [{\sin(nx)-icos(nx)\over n}]_{0}^{2\pi} = 0$ 
Because $\\sin(2\pi n)=\sin(0)=0$ and $\\cos(2\pi n)=\cos(0)=1$

Comment: @Lag: You have to be super careful with the $n=0$ case, because there, $\sin{(2 \pi n)}/n = 2 \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Parseval's identity is a good idea.

Let $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ke^{ikx}$ --- Fourier series, then the Parseval's identity is
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x)|^2\,dx = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}|c_k|^2
$$

Your function $f(x) = 3+4e^{10ix}+5e^{100ix}$, (this means, that $c_0$=3, $c_10$=4 and so on). In this case Parseval's identity is
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|3+4e^{10ix}+5e^{100ix}|^2\,dx
= 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2. 
$$